# Add assembly and debug symbols (pdb files) to GAC - Wix Installer

Tags: assemblies, wix, gac

I am using Wix Installer (3) for deploying my application. How can I add both the output dll from one of the projects in my solution and the debug symbols (pdb files) to the GAC? (I have a C# application developed in Visual Studio 2008)

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to put the symbols in the GAC in order for the system to pick them up.
You can for example put the symbols under %WINDIR%\System32\Symbols\dll (for dlls) and %WINDIR%\System32\Symbols\exe (for... well, exes) the draw back of this is that you only have one pdb per dll\exe while the GAC allows you to have multiple versions so only the latest install will have its symbols, if you have only one version then its not a real problem.

Comment: It appears I had to use %windir%\Symbols\dll however I can't find any documentation on how this is intended to work (or if it should even work) any ideas? The closest I can find is documentation in the Visual Studio 2010 RTM mentioning that it should be set as a path for debugging the Native Parallel Library.

Comment: More searching yielded this MSDN Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2007/06/21/customizing-pdb-lookup-for-source-information-in-stacktrace.aspx apparently it will respect _NT_SYMBOL_PATH but there does not appear to be any contractual obligation towards any paths.

Comment: Replacement link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rmbyers/customizing-pdb-lookup-for-source-information-in-stacktrace